# Python Selenium and FireFox \ geckodriver

Tags: python, selenium

I am currently trying to use selenium on a new machine and I am running into the problem and error of:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: %s If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details
```

I have read the following post about this and I can't seem to get this to work.

I am just using a simple test of:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://google.com')
```

I am using:

> Firefox version 51.0.1 (32-bit)
>
> I have tried both selenium version 2.53.6 and 3.0.2
>
> I have tried to download the Geckodriver and added to the system
>   variable path.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong. Should I use an older version of selenium or am I doing something wrong with the driver?

Any help here will be great.

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same issue.

Here is how I resolved it.

1. Uninstall Selenium
2. Install it again with `pip install selenium`
3. Install Geckodriver with Homebrew: `brew install Geckodriver`
4. Append the hombrew install Geckodriver path to your driver instantiation: `driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')`

Hope this helps

Comment: sudo cp /usr/local/Cellar/geckodriver/0.16.1/bin/geckodriver /usr/bin/ did the trick. No need to inform executable_path.

Comment: Good stuff! Will give it a spin.